# IE8 not releasing memory for image elements

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, garbage-collection

I have a JavaScript widget that switches between image frames to create motion,
the widget fetches these frames when its **render** method is called, and discards reference to them when the **dispose** method is called.

The implementation works by using PreloadJS (http://www.createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS/documentation) to load a set of frames, it then renders the current frame to a *<canvas>*, or toggles display:none and display:block on the image elements on legacy browsers.

IE8 is causing issues because it doesn't want to free up the memory from these frames when the dispose method is called. *(Note: This only happens if the images are in the DOM, otherwise everything is okay.)*

The complete source can be found here: http://pastie.org/8061442

The images are added to the DOM on line 201:

```
    var i = 0, img, node = self.$node[0];

    for ( ; i < self.imageSet.length; i += 1 ) {

        img = self.queue._loadedResults[self.imageSet[i]]

        img.setAttribute("draggable", "false")

        img.style.display = "none"

        node.appendChild(img)

        img = null
    }

    i = node = null
```

If this code is removed (and the accompanying disposal code here [on :251-259](http://pastie.org/8061442#251-259)) then the images are disposed correctly, it's only when the elements are added to the DOM that there is a problem.

If the render method is called after the dispose fails, the classic `Stack verflow at line: 0` error gets thrown.

Any ideas / suggestions would be very helpful. Please look at the code before suggesting though, all references to the images has been nulled and the instance of the image loader has been disposed also, there are no event listeners on the image elements that would create a circular reference, etc. As far as I can see the images should be freed.

Comment: I noticed that this posting is quite old, is there any chance you found a simple solution for this problem?  I am having the same error on a current project of mine.

Comment: I spent a lot of time researching a solution and came to the conclusion that it's a bug in the javascript engine for IE8 (and the problem still exists to some extent in IE9) so there was no solution to this. No matter how good you are at keeping track of references and nulling them the problem will persist in one form or another. My solution was to half the number of frames in IE8/9 in order to keep stable, but obviously you might not be able to do this in your project if all of your assets are required.

Comment: Thanks, I came to the same conclusion but was wanting some confirmation. In the end I just forced the browser to reload everything every refresh.  Imho, people using IE are already used to poor results, so it was not a horrible sacrifice to invalidated the cached images.